# Adding element to Iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I am creating a page which contains iframe. My aim is to create a javascript that will add  to the head of the iframe content.

But I always get the error implying iframe.contentDocument is null.

Code for main page

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Sample "Hello, World" Application</title>
<script type="text/javascript" >
function sizeFrame() {
try{
    var ifrm = document.getElementById("CFrame");
    var bt = ifrm.contentDocument.createElement("base");
    bt.setAttribute("target", "_parent");
    ifrm.contentDocument.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(bt);
}
catch (er)
{alert(er);}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="sidecontainer">
<iframe id="SFrame" name="SearchFrame" frameborder ="0" width="500" height="100" scrolling="no" src="SearchBox.html"></iframe>
</div>
<div id="content">
<iframe id="CFrame" name="ContentFrame" frameborder="0" height="1000px" width="1000px" onload="sizeFrame()" scrolling="no" src="ContentFrame.html"></iframe>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Code for the Iframe ContentFrame.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="input">
    test
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you try

```
ifrm.contentWindow.document.getElementById("id")
```

Comment: Thanks, another error (TypeError: Cannot getElementById of undefined).   And the requirement changed, so now I need to create a new "base" tag and add it to the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Use the frame window name to create your element as you do in the main window like the following

```
ContentFrame.document...
```

In other word access the window name.

In addition your iframe window does not has any element with id value equals to "id".